# Is there a function such that

Tags: combinatorics, functions, discrete-mathematics

Let $A_n=\{1,2,...,n\}$. Is there a function $f:A_n^{n-1}\rightarrow A_n$ such that for all $(a_1,a_2,...,a_n)\in A_n^{n}$, there exist $i\in A_n$ such that $f(a_1,...,a_{i-1},a_{i+1},...,a_n)=a_i$ ?

For $n=2$, it is easy to check that a function satisfying this condition doesn't exist.

But how to find the function for $n\geq3$ ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such $f$ for any $n>1$.  I will give the argument for $n=4$; the general case is similar but more notationally cumbersome.

Suppose such an $f$ exists for $n=4$, and fix two distinct elements $a,b\in A_n$.  Considering the $4$-tuple $(a,a,a,a)$, we see that $f(a,a,a)=a$.  Now consider the $4$-tuple $(a,a,a,b)$.  Since $f(a,a,a)=a\neq b$, in order for your condition to be satisfied we must have $f(a,a,b)=a$.  Similarly, $(a,a,b,b)$ gives that $f(a,b,b)=a$ and $(a,b,b,b)$ gives that $f(b,b,b)=a$.  But then your condition fails for $(b,b,b,b)$, which is a contradiction.

(Note that this argument only requires that $A_n$ has at least two elements, and in fact works for $n=1$ as well if you replace $A_1$ by a set with at least two elements.)